# Laravel request()->fingerprint() function and possibility of encrypted user data logging?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

Doc: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_fingerprint

If I add the fingerprint function to the log, for example;

```
LOG::info('Delete Admin', [
            '(loggedin) User ID' => Auth::guard()->id(),
            'User Ip' => request()->ip(),
            'Fingerprint'   => request()->fingerprint(),
            ]);
```

I get a sha1 unique fingerprint for the request / route / IP address.

**My question is:**
When should I use this and how do I use this (read the content of the encrypted key)?

Bonus, but not main question:
Will it allow me to identify who did the request to, for example delete the Admin, even 2 years into the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sha1 is not an encryption method as such, it's a hashing method. The difference between encryption and hashing is that hashing is not reversible. So you can never "decrypt" (or unhash) the Sha1 value to get the original request data.

You could just store the request data in a table somewhere, and use the elocryptfive package (search on github or packagist) to store the data as encrypted, allowing you to decrypt it later.

Comment: So If I understand correctly, the hashed fingerprint by itself is useless if I do not also save the request, route and IP (from which the fingerprint was derived) separately?

Comment: Correct, except just for verification purposes